# OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient: what to pass on extraData IDictionary?

Tags: asp.net, oauth, google-api, google-oauth

[MSDN Library document about RegisterGoogleClient()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj158358%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) shows I can pass `IDictionary<string, Object> extraData`, without any further description.

Does anybody have any more information about this? Is this an easier way to request extra information like first and last name from Google, without [Plugging custom OAuth/OpenID providers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranav_rastogi/archive/2012/08/23/plugging-custom-oauth-openid-providers.aspx)?

Comment: depends on what you are doing but you could use the Google plus-> people API to search for a user.  Are they logging in with there Google accounts?

Comment: Right. RegisterGoogleAccount() is used by Visual Studio's boilerplate web application for external login. It gives email only, but the link I put above shows how to get additional info like first and last name. I wonder if extraData can do the job.

Comment: There is an issue with [Plugging custom OAuth/OpenID providers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranav_rastogi/archive/2012/08/23/plugging-custom-oauth-openid-providers.aspx) - it asks the user for permission every time. Not sure if it was a change from google side.

Comment: Any reason your not using Googles dot net client lib?https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth/